# VGA output working, but no signal on DVI?

Tags: windows-vista, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have a Radeon 6570 graphics card with HDMI, VGA, and DVI outputs.

How do you configure it to use multiple displays? Just connecting the monitors to the VGA and DVI outputs is not working. The VGA output works, but there is no signal on DVI.
Is there an option in Catalyst that I'm missing to enable the DVI output?

EDIT: Opened a support ticket with XFX... Let's see how that turns out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, XFX got back to me about that issue: The monitor I was attaching is a VGA, so I was using a DVI/VGA converter. The DVI port on that card is a DVI-D, which is incompatible with VGA.

Answer (score 1):

Open Display Properties (right click on desktop and select properties, or go to control panel). Go to the Settings tab. How many different screens show up in the top part of that window? There should generally be one for each possible connector on the card.

Right click on the screen corresponding to the connector you wish to send signals to and select Attached. Press Apply to submit the change. The monitor should generally come on within a couple seconds.

Adjust settings as desired to set primary display, resolution, etc.

Comment: still blank, when I connect a monitor to the DVI, it always says 'no input signal', if 'attached' is selected or not

Comment: You've tried "Attaching" all the possible screens (besides "1" which is probably the VGA)? Howabout connecting only the DVI and rebooting the computer?

Comment: when I originally installed the card, I connected the DVI but got no input signal so I just put a VGA monitor on and haven't tried the DVI til now

Comment: At this point I do not know what to check. If I had the card itself I'd look and see if there are ways to isolate or analyze the issues, but without the card I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: I think I may have found something - The first time I tried selecting 'attached' I just clicked it and hit 'enter', closing the window, but nothing happened. When I reopened it, 'attached' was deselected. When I tried reselecting 'attached', I hit 'apply' (which doesn't close the window) and after the "Do you want to keep these settings" dialog closed, 'attached' had deselcted by itself

Comment: If selecting Attached and pressing Apply results in the image greying out again, it usually means the system is encountering some issue enabling that output. In cases where this has been consistently an issue, I'll boot into safe mode and remove the device completely, boot back into normal mode and completely reinstall the drivers with a fresh set.

Comment: nope. I reinstalled everything even remotely associated with ATI and it still doesn't work. Are there any known issues with using a legacy monitor?

Comment: Shouldn't be. You've made sure that the monitor works on other connectors?

Comment: I just disconnected it from an older computer to test the multi-monitor setup

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved same issue. My Motherboard MSI 890GXM has two pci-e 16x slots. If I put the graphic card (ATI HD 6570) in the second slot (far from processor) only VGA or HDMI ports are working (but not in dual monitor mode). The PC detects the monitor and the monitor detects PC connection, but it stays black (looks like a sleep mode).

After I put the graphic card in the first slot (I needed to saw a cooling radiator a bit) it works perfectly in every combination.

I do not know what was the cause of such behavior. I suppose the second pci-e slot is connected with less than 16 lanes and the graphic card don't manage to detect it.