# Multi monitor with separate outputs?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, graphics, dvi

My graphics card (HD 6570) only has one DVI, HDMI, and VGA port. The DVI port already houses a monitor, and I have a spare VGA monitor that I would like to use in a multi monitor setup, but I'm not sure if it is possible - is it?

Comment: What stopped you testing it?

Comment: Does this possible duplicate of [VGA output working, but no signal on DVI?](http://superuser.com/questions/359998/vga-output-working-but-no-signal-on-dvi) help?

Comment: Nothing yet. Unless sometime answers saying its not possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. Many people struggle with 3 monitors but it will work fine with 2...

One of the many, *many* forums out there explaining how to get it working in case you run into problems: http://www.overclock.net/t/1203606/ati-radeon-hd-6570-wont-duel-monitor

Or a video if easier http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvF9Ep_odxE

Or, try using Google with a phrase like `HD 6570 vga and dvi dual monitor`

Comment: Just tested it. Worked out of the box on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible.

Hook up the VGA monitor with a VGA cable to your VGA port on your graphics card (keep the DVI cable plugged in of course). Make sure both monitors are powered (of course).

Assuming you are running Windows vista/7/8, it will automatically detect both monitors and mirror them. (You see the same on both monitors). In order to have your desktop extended (have different stuff on each screen), right-click your desktop and select "Screen Resolution". there you shoudl see two images each representing one of your monitors. In the "Multiple Displays" dropdown box select "Extend these displays".

That should be it. Have fun.